# How to get Solr console to output the commands used to perform an action?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am following a tutorial and (just like in the official tutorial) when you execute a command with Solr if outputs the commands that were sent to, and received from, the Solr server to perform the action like so:

```
 $  bin/solr create_core -c films
WARNING: Using _default configset. Data driven schema functionality is enabled
by default, which is NOT RECOMMENDED for production use.

         To turn it off:
            curl http://localhost:8983/solr/films/config -d
            '{"set-user-property": {"update.autoCreateFields":"false"}}'

Copying configuration to new core instance directory:
/home/paul/solr-7.0.0/server/solr/films

Creating new core 'films' using command:
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=films&instanceDire=films

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime:1222},
  "core":"films"}
```

When I run the same command I get

```
bin/solr create_core -c films
WARNING: Using _default configset with data driven schema functionality. NOT RECOMMENDED for production use.
         To turn off: bin/solr config -c films -p 8983 -action set-user-property -property update.autoCreateFields -value false
INFO  - 2018-12-07 10:00:10.021; org.apache.solr.util.configuration.SSLCredentialProviderFactory; Processing SSL Credential Provider chain: env;sysprop

Created new core 'films'
```

How Do I get my Solr commancds to output the extra information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the `-V` argument when invoking `bin/solr`:

```
-V            Enable more verbose output.
```

.. making the end command be `bin/solr create_core -c films -V`.